# what heuristic evaluation function or algorithm can be treated as inadmissible

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I have learned several heuristic functions which are admissible to deal with the classical 8 puzzle problem, and I know you can multiply a factor to a admissible function to make it inadmissible, however, I wonder is there any other inadmissible heuristic function for the 8 puzzle problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are all sorts of inadmissible heuristics to this puzzle.  An inadmissible heuristic just needs to overestimate the number of steps it will take to solve a given puzzle, and so one simple inadmissible heuristic would be

```
h(S) = infinity
```

Since any puzzle that's solvable can be solved in fewer than infinity steps, the heuristic is inadmissible.

A much trickier and more interesting question would be what good *admissible* heuristics are out there, since they require you to give the largest possible value you can that doesn't overestimate the distance.  For that, I don't have a good answer. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef: Thanks for the answer, but what's the good for inadmissible, for example, if you set h(S)=infinity, basically, the search algorithm will eventually try all the states in the state space, I've seen something like inadmissible can speed up sometime

Comment: @starcaller- Inadmissible heuristics don't mean that you won't find a valid answer; rather, it means that your A* search is not guaranteed to give you an optimal solution to the problem.  If you use the infinite heuristic, you'll explore every possible state, which at some point might give you a solution.  It's just that there's absolutely no guarantee that the solution you find uses the optimal number of moves.

Comment: @templatetypedef: then why would I use the inadmissible heuristic, it's like bfs, every state will be examined.

Comment: @templatetypedef: also, am I correct to say that I can multiply a factor to a admissible heuristic function to make it inadmissible?

Comment: @starcaller- You would want to use an admissible heuristic because it dramatically increases the rate at which your search progresses.  In a graph with a high branching factor, using an admissible heuristic can avoid exploring exponentially many states if the heuristic is good enough; in fact, given a perfect heuristic (one that actually tells you the distance) you will only explore states that actually get you to the solution.  An inadmissible heuristic can result in an exponential explosion of states to be explored, exhausting either time or memory.

Comment: @starcaller- And yes, for any (nonzero) admissible heuristic there is a constant you can scale it by to make it inadmissible.  For example, take the maximum cost of any solution, add one, divide it by the smallest nonzero value handed back by the heuristic, then multiply the heuristic value by this constant.  All nonzero values the heuristic hands back will be above the max solution cost and thus inadmissible.

Answer (score 3):

Heuristic evaluation function estimates the cost of an optimal path between a pair of states in a single-agent path-finding problem.

Read more on [Heuristic evaluation function](http://intelligence.worldofcomputing.net/ai-search/heuristic-evaluation-function.html) article.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, any function that overestimates cost is inadmissible, which means that constructing inadmissible functions is easy.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) has a good description